# Is Facebook capable to read through MS Access database before input?

Tags: facebook, ms-access-2007

How can I set up a business facebook page that when a user enters an email it will run through the company's database and ensure they are not already there before inputting the information into the database. I would like it to display a message to the user like, "Thanks you are already registered with us". I also need it to allow the user to still have access to the page. Sorry if this seems basic, but I have spent quite a while researching this and I believe it would be putting additional code in the authentication part, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks!
Jennifer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you are correct - the functionality you are looking for would require additional authentication code in the form of server-side scripts.  Only in that way would you be able to authenticate your users by cross referencing username/password or email values in your company's database.

If you yourself are a programmer then I would recommend looking into PHP for the server-side scripting and a mysql database (if the database does not already exist in another form - *cringe*).
Both PHP and mysql are free to use and there is a large knowledge base on the internet.
Here are some links to get you started. 
Don't be afraid to jump in - the water is lovely :P

[Basic PHP Tutorial from Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627)

[Basic Mysql Tutorial from Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/)

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately the database is already set up in MS Access, I am much more familiar with SQL. I have had experience in C#, but nothing in the ways of html or java so this is all new to me. I will definitely check out the links you recommended. Thanks again :)

Comment: no problem! please mark this question as "answered" by clicking the check mark next to the answer.
There is/are [C# facebook SDK's](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) out there though.

Comment: The database portion of this is by far the most trivial aspect of it.